# Why nginx server file upload always fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

The specific situation is:
I have a app (rails + passenger + nginx), which provides a upload function to users to upload files. I deployed to the server after the test

1. use my computer file upload all ok
2. with my company computer upload files also ok
3. provide for your partner, when uploading files to half page link interrupt.
4. partners with his company's computer upload, also is the upload half discontinue links.
5. collaborations sometimes can upload (the risk is small) most is half page they upload blocked

I log on to the server, and view the log found and what happened without exception.

PS: partners did before heavy system (in has not do system before uploading). Use firefox browser is, also used ie browser failed
My guess is that of partners network problems. There is also a may be my nginx configuration out the problem.
There is no find the right starting point to check the problem. First question stick out, hope to help everybody to give an idea

Below is my nignx config:

```
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format  simple '$remote_addr - [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent';
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  180;


    include /opt/nginx/conf/sites-enabled/*;
```

Comment: Is everybody uploading to the same server? How large are the files? Are there any proxies or other systems in the middle that could be affecting the request?

Comment: no. just some like that. when i use my mac upload it's ok. those file just 1~10 MB and also i set nginx client_body to 1024 MB. i am not sure the proxies. how can i konw the proixes?

Comment: so it's not a size issue? client_max_body_size  ?